# Bootstrap Dynamic Modals With AJAX Calling

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm using **codeigniter v3** and **bootstrap v3**.
I've a table for messages and for every message in table, when click on details button, a bootstrap **modal** show the details.
In a for loop, I print table rows and for every row (at end of the loop), I put whole bootstrap modal structure.
My question is: **how could do this with ajax calling?** I mean, I don't put all modal code for every table row (every message) and every time that details button clicked, I handle showing modal with ajax.
thanks for attention.

**SOLVED:**
I find an easy and I think better way in the bootstrap official website: **Using data- attribute.**
I show it with an working example for who that could not achieve better solution:

Suppose we want to fill a table body with some data (as my problem):

```
//just table body code
<tbody>
 <?php foreach($fields as $field): ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php $field->some_field; ?></td>
   //other <td> elements
   <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
       data-time="<?php echo $field->time; ?>">Show Details</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

So in a loop, I read data (that in controller, get with model's method, and pass to view with $data['fields']). Now for showing some details in modal, I use **HTML5 data attribute**. Suppose, I want to show **time** in the modal. As you see in above code, I put time field in data-time:

```
data-time="<?php echo $field->time; ?>"
```

Now I create a modal as template (you could see whole modal structure in bootstrap official website) and put it out of loop (one modal for all table rows; dynamic data). in the following code, I put an element in the modal body (as a placeholder):

```
//... in the modal body section
<h4 id="time"></h4>
```

This element have no content, because I want to retrieve every row time filed and put it in this element. Note this will be practical with defining an id. Now some script:

```
//first load jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
   var btn = $(event.relatedTarget); // find which button is clicked

   var time = btn.data('time'); //get the time data attribute

   $('#time').text(time); //put the data value in the element which set in the modal with an id
  });
 });
</script>
```

You could define more data attribute and retrieve in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I will not write the code for you, but show you the way:

- You just need one modal for the whole page and it works like a template.
- You need same data/informations to be displayed in the modal. This data you can pick up via Javascript/jQuery from your HTML. I prefer data attributes for that. Something like:

> data-modal-title="My Title" data-modal-content="My Content"

- Now you inject this data in your modal template and open the modal via Javascript.